# Como obtener un archivo HTML con ClassLoader Java

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Hola amigos de stackoverflow, tengo problemas para obtener un archivo con `ClassLoader` de Java, estoy usando para ello una pequeña linea que me evita poner toda la ruta del archivo un ejemplo:

```
 Class clase = Prueba.class;
```

y luego lo guardo en un

`InputStream inputStream = clase.getResourceAsStream("/nombreDeMiRecurso.html");`

archivo para poderlo leer posteriormente, pero siempre me retorna:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
>         at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
>
>         at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
> ```

Tengo entendido que en el proyecto java al crear un recurso se copia automáticamente dentro de la carpeta donde están los archivos `.class`
Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal se los agradezco, el archivo en sí lo puedo leer normalmente con `FileReader y BufferedeReader` pero lo quiero hacer usando `ClassLoader`, un saludo a todos.

Comment: pon la estructura de tu sistema de ficheros y que usas para compilar. Especifica igual si empaquetas (war,ear, jar) o no (exploded) para correr en tu servidor

Comment: Nombre_del_proyecto/Modulo1/src/main/resources/nombredemirecurso.html

Utilizo `mvn test ` y de empaquetado un test.war

@RuslanLópez

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón específica por la que quieras un flujo y no un puntero al recurso?

Comment: @RuslanLópez una disculpa pero no entiendo a que te refieres con flujo y puntero al recurso, si me lo puedes explicar por favor :)

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io

Answer (score 1):

Tenes dos formas de leer recursos que están en classpath:

```
InputStream inputStream = clase.getResourceAsStream("/nombreDeMiRecurso.html");
```

En este caso la "/" indica que el recurso está en la raíz del classpath.
Si no se incluye la "/", se buscar el recurso dentro del package de `clase`.

La segunda forma de leer recursos es con:

```
clase.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("nombreDeMiRecurso.html");
```

No lleva "/" y busca en la raíz del classpath.

Ejemplo:

```
/com
  /midom
    /miproyecto
      /MiClase.class
      /un-archivo.html

Class clazz = MiClase.class;

1) clazz.getResourceAsStream("un-archivo.html");
2) clazz.getResourceAsStream("/com/midom/miproyecto/un-archivo.html");
3) clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/midom/miproyecto/un-archivo.html");
```